# MySql join tables and add column if 2 other columns are same

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables, and display year(date),total and vehicle type.
If year and vehicle_type is the same then their total should be combined. This is my query.

```
select extract(year from ra.roadAccident_date) as 'Year', 
       c.casualties_death + c.casualties_serious + c.casualties_minor as 'Total',
       ra.vehicle_type as 'Types of Vehicle'
from casualties c
join roadAccidents ra
on (c.accident_id = ra.accident_id)
```

My results are

```
Year  Total Types of Vehicle
2014    6   taxi
2014    9   lorry
2014    3   bus
2014    16  bus
2015    7   taxi
2015    5   lorry
2015    7   lorry
2016    2   bus
2016    5   lorry
2016    9   bus
```

For 2014, i want vehicle type bus to be combined to one row with total 19. I tried multiple `group by` methods but could not find the one I am looking for.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why a simple `GROUP BY` won't work:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ra.roadAccident_date) AS 'Year',
    SUM(c.casualties_death + c.casualties_serious + c.casualties_minor) AS 'Total',
    ra.vehicle_type AS 'Types of Vehicle'
FROM casualties c
INNER JOIN roadAccidents ra
    USING accident_id
GROUP BY ra.vehicle_type, YEAR(ra.roadAccident_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing (as a subquery) with a grouping outer one, like

```
Select yr,vtype, sum(total) as tot from 
(
select extract(year from ra.roadAccident_date) as yr, 
   c.casualties_death +c.casualties_serious+c.casualties_minor as total
   ra.vehicle_type as vtype
from casualties c
join roadAccidents ra on (c.accident_id = ra.accident_id)
) stats group by yr, vtype
```